# Trouble while taking input and passing into getters and setters

Tags: getter-setter, getter

I am facing trouble while i am trying to pass String followed by integer and then double value to getter and setter and printing the result inside main method.

Here is the code::

```
System.out.println("Enter Name Height Weight Of Dog: ");
z = sc.nextLine();
x1=sc.next();
x = Integer.parseInt(x1);
y1=sc.next();
y = Double.parseDouble(y1);

d1.setName(z);
name = d1.getName();
d1.setHeight(x);
height = d1.getHeight();
d1.setWeight(y);
weight = d1.getWeight();
```

}

Comment: Welcome Mayank to Stack Overflow. Please explain what kind of trouble / error messages you are getting to help steer people helping you. Please read how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The values for name height and weight is not getting printed on the command line if i take input in the order as first string, then int and lastly double. can anyone solve my problem???